# Automatic dot in dates - Passing value between 2 functions or something else?

Tags: javascript, function

So I'm trying to figure out how to set the dot automatically in a date field on a website.
I'm using this here right now

```
function dots() {

  var chars = document.f.vRGDate.value.length;
  var text = document.f.vRGDate.value;

  if (chars == 2) {
    document.f.vRGDate.value = text+".";
  }
  if (chars == 5) {
    document.f.vRGDate.value = text+".";
  }
}
```

HTML Part of that :

```
<tr>
  <td width="130">Reg. Date</td>
  <td width="50">
    <input type="text" name="vRGDate" value="" size="10" onKeyDown="return isNumberKey(event);" onkeyup="dots();">
  </td>
```

So far it works - Whats annoying me is that you have to HOLD Down Backspace to delete something. Else it always generates this dot.

So I tried it with some onKeyDown function

```
function isNumberKey(evt)
{
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode

  // Left, Right, Backspace, DEL
  if(charCode==37||charCode==39||charCode==46 || charCode==8){
    return false;
  }
  else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Now when I press one of those 4 keys it blocks me them due to "return false".
But this is the part where I don't know anymore. I thought about using a value in the isNumberKey function and passing that to the dots function but I have no clue how.. And if it would work. Does anyone knows what to do?

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree totally with Avish, you should validate the user input after they have finished, i.e when focus is lost on the inputbox.

If you do however want to ignore his warning, you can implement it as follows:

HTML

```
<tr>
<td width="130">Reg. Date</td>
<td width="50">
    <input type="text" MaxLength="10" id="vRGDate" name="vRGDate" value="" size="10"         onKeyDown="isNumberKey(event);">
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function dots(){
   var dateBox = document.getElementById('vRGDate')
   var chars = dateBox.value.length;
   var text = dateBox.value;

   if (chars == 2) {
       dateBox.value = text + ".";
   }
   if (chars == 5) {
       dateBox.value = text + ".";
   }

}

function isNumberKey(evt){
   var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode

   // CHECK IF NUMBER
   if((charCode >=48 && charCode<=57) || (charCode>=96 && charCode<=105)){
      //IF KEY IS A NUMBER CALL DOTS
      dots();
   }
   else if(charCode==37||charCode==39||charCode==46 || charCode==8){
      // LET LEFT RIGHT BACKSPACE AND DEL PASS
   }
   else{
      // BLOCK ALL OTHER KEYS
      evt.preventDefault();
   }
}
```

Beware that users can still input invalid dates i.e "99.99.9999"

You can test this using the folling JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7JY4Z/

Only my 2nd reply hope it helps

Adam

Comment: That was exactly what I was searching for! Thanks alot!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your test for metacharacters belongs in the "dots" function, not in the "isnumberkey" function.

Basically you want to say:

- I only accept number keys or one of the supported meta-keys (arrow keys, backspace, del etc.)
- Once you've typed a key, if it's not a meta-key, I'll insert the relevant dot automatically
- (Optional) once you've typed a key, if it's a deletion key, I'll remove the relevant dot automatically.

The first bullet can be expressed in your `onkeydown` function, while the other two should be handled in a `onkeyup` or `change` handler.

I must add that this kind of UX can be very frustrating; many users, myself included, would prefer to type whatever they want into the textbox, and have auto-formatting applied only after they leave the input field (e.g. on a `blur` event).